# File picker not working in IOS

Tags: filepicker.io

I have a responsive web app which is using Ink to pick image files. It has been working perfectly a couple of days back but now it is working in the computer browser but not in Iphone. Does nayone else has the same error?

If you open this https://www.inkfilepicker.com/demos/ in your iphone and try to upload a file you will the issue there.

Comment: The issue is with safari on ios. It is working perfectly fine with Chrome on IOS.